# Is There an Overkill on Bribes?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I'm looking at the Final Fantasy X bribes bestiary.
[image]

Each bribe amount is followed by parenthesis. What does that mean?

For example, the Chimera Brain's bribe field reads:
196,000 Lv. 4 Key Sphere x 1(2)

Is there an Overkill for bribes or something? I just keep getting 1 every time I try.

Comment: I can't find any definitive information on this, so I won't post an answer. It seems that Bribe can reward anywhere between 50% and 150% of the reward. Furthermore, you should be able to succeed even when bribing for a lower amount than listed. There's also some discussions that you can bribe for 1 gil after missing, but I haven't actually had that much experience with Bribe myself.

Comment: @IvoCoumans Your bribes are certainly cumulative. If I miss on the first Bribe I continue to bribe 1 gil until the amount is accepted. (But then maybe that's why I'm not getting the "Overkill Bribe"...

Comment: @IvoCoumans I think your comment is the answer, it appears that the bestiary lists the base value, and in parenthesis the maximum value, that is 150% of the base value. This is really your information so if you care to post that I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bribes appear to have a minimum value, and a maximum value. As found in [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643146-final-fantasy-x-x-2-hd-remaster/69018642), the rewards can range between 50% and 150%. When working with small values, like 1 or 2 items, this is rounded by the game. So, in your example, this would mean that **1** is the minimum value, and **(2)** is the maximum value.

Furthermore, there's some speculation that bribing can even succeed with a lower amount than listed, but with a much lower chance. I haven't much experience in regards to this myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

Bribe doesn't overkill, if they accept the bribe the enemy simply leaves the fight.

To prove this you can go to some enemies in the early game after you get the airship and save, then bribe an enemy using all your money, it still just simply succeeds - no overkill.

More money does mean more of the item, but it depends on how much you give and what item you're getting, my advice would be to save scrub it, and work out what the best figure is for the item you are trying to accumulate.